# Can't Drag Dynamically Appended DIV Angular2 Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

When I add a directive that permit to me to apply my drag and drop in the tag wich I will add dynamically `<p dnd [drop]=true></p>` the dnd is not applicable on tag P

there are any solution to considere this tag P as a static tag ?

I'm Using gridmanager jquery

```
  gm.addEditableAreaClick = function (container, btn) {
                var cTagOpen = '<!--' + gm.options.gmEditRegion + '-->',
                    cTagClose = '<!--\/' + gm.options.gmEditRegion + '-->',
                    elem = null;
                $(('.' + gm.options.gmToolClass + ':last'), container)
                    .before(elem = $('<div>').addClass(gm.options.gmEditRegion + ' ' + gm.options.contentDraggableClass)
                        .append(gm.options.controlContentElem + '<div  class="' + gm.options.gmContentRegion + '"><p dnd **[drop]="true"**>New Content</p></div>'))
                    .before(cTagClose).prev().before(cTagOpen);
                gm.initNewContentElem(elem);
            }; <== this code is from gridmanager.js
```

the tag

is created dynamically in my page so in need to apply a drag on this div

```
<li dnd >value</li>  <== this code is from component.html
```

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: addEditableAreaClick this function add dymaically a paragraph to my Div so I need to do a drag on this paragraph (it clear ?)